# angularjs: access jquery variable in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

angular js code

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('PostsController',  function($scope, $window, $http){

  $scope.$watch('selectedCities', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if(newValue === oldValue ){
      return;
    }
    //to call a jQuery variable wookmark

  }, true);
}
```

jquery code

```
 $(function ($) {
      var container = '#wookmark_container',
          $container = $(container),
          tileCount = 30,
          $window = $(window),
          $document = $(document),
          wookmark;

      // Initialize Wookmark
      wookmark = new Wookmark(container, {
        offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
        outerOffset: 10, // Optional, the distance to the containers border
        itemWidth: 260, // Optional, the width of a grid item
        autoResize: true
      });

    });
```

What I am trying to do is if a select options changes I would like to reload a wookmark jquery plugin.

Is it doable to call a jquery vairable in angularjs?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to create directive for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference any variable that's in the scope of your Angular controller.

It looks like you have `woodmark` defined inside its own function scope, which means you don't have access to it. To access it, you need to set it as a property of the global window object like so:

```
window.woodwork =  "initial value";
```

You can then reference it in your controller using `$window` service.

```
$window.woodwork = "updated value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. Declare variable 'wookmark' in the parent or global scope i.e. outside ready block. This will make that variable accessible in the everywhere. You will be able to access it in angular's controller

   ```
   var woomark;

   $(function ($) {
      // Initialize Wookmark
      wookmark = new Wookmark(container, {...});
   });
   ```
2. To reload the woomark plugin, you can give a call as shown below in your code.

   `angular.element(document.querySelector('#wookmark_container')).trigger('refreshWookmark');`

or directly

```
$('#wookmark_container').trigger('refreshWookmark')
```

Here is the documentation link for 'refreshWookmark'
https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery